# Is there an efficient way of deleting already allocated but empty Eigen rows without reallocation?

Tags: c++, performance, reshape, eigen, memory-efficient

I am trying to write runtime efficient code using Eigen::Matrix class. To improve runtime I know that resizing the Eigen::Matrix is recommended such that sufficient memory is allocated and thus avoiding reallocation. However, I don't know the number of rows at compiletime nor at initialization of the matrix. What I want to do is to use a matrix of dynamic size, allocate memory with a known upper limit, then fill some data into the matrix and finally "cutoff/reshape" the lowerend rows that I didn't need.

So my problem looks like thus, except for the memory I allocate is way larger than (5,3)

```
    Eigen::MatrixXi M;
    M.resize(5,3);
    std::cout << "M size: (" << M.rows() << "x" << M.cols()<< " ) with Entries:\n"<< M << std::endl;
    M.row(0) = Eigen::RowVector3i(1, 1, 1);
    M.row(1) = Eigen::RowVector3i(2, 2, 2);
    M.row(2) = Eigen::RowVector3i(3, 3, 3);
    //M.reshape(3, 3); ??
    std::cout << "M size: (" << M.rows() << "x" << M.cols() << " ) with Entries:\n" << M << std::endl;
```

I know that the following code would work but this snippet includes reallocation of new memory instead of just "freeing" the lower rows of M or remapping the memory of M;

```
    // works but inefficient
    Eigen::MatrixXi M2;
    M2.resize(3, 3);
    M2 = M.topRows(3);
```

Do you have any ideas on how I can implement this idea more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are adding entries row-by-row, it could be more efficient to use a row-major matrix. Also, if the number of columns is known at compile-time to be 3, you can express this in the type:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> MatrixRX3i;
MatrixRX3i M;
M.resize(5,3);
```

If you don't mind that the entire memory of `M` is kept all the time, you can define `M2` as an `Eigen::Ref` object:

```
Eigen::Ref<MatrixRX3i> M2(M.topRows(3));
```

If you want to deallocate unnecessary memory, you should use [`conservativeResize()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a712c25be1652e5a64a00f28c8ed11462):

```
M.conservativeResize(3,3);
```

Ideally, this should just call `std::realloc` (in case the inner dimension does not change), though there might be some alignment related corner-cases.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I think that answers my question and I will work with that from now on!
is there an actual performance increase when I define the known dimension at compile time even though the other one is dynamic or ist that just some sort of "good style"?

Comment: Regarding compile time dimensions: On the one hand, this is "good style", but it does allow Eigen to unroll small loops. Whether that really makes a difference in your case depends on a lot of factors, so just try it out and decide yourself ...

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about the loop unrollment but that sounds reasonable. I will give it a try and track the runtimes.